# black box robotium, targeting an element is problematic if they have the same id

Tags: android, eclipse, automation, robotium, getview

Im hoping someone can help me out with this, in ddms hierarchy is as follows:

```
(0) ListView
    (0) LinearLayout
        (0) LinearLayout
            (0)TextView:Value 1
            (1)TextView:Value 2
            (2)TextView:Value 3
        (1)View
        (2) LinearLayout
    (1) LinearLayout
        (0) LinearLayout
            (0)TextView:Value 4
            (1)TextView:Value 5
            (2)TextView:Value 6
        (1)View
        (2) LinearLayout
```

What im trying to do is use robotium to confirm the values in the text views. my problem is the second set of views have the same resource-id, for example Value 1 and Value 4 both have a resource id of com.myapp.this:id/TopEntry

is there any way to use robotium to target views in a stepwise manner i.e get view 0,1,0 etc.

currently my code to check the content of a view is:

```
public String checkView(String theview, String expected)

{
       string actual = "";
       string result = "";
       TextView view = (TextView) solo.getView(theview);
       actual = (String) view.getText();
       assertEquals("viewChecked",expected,actual);

--------- code continues ---------------


}
```

so for my example i would be calling the code by using:

```
checkView("TopEntry","Value 1");
checkView("TopEntry","Value 4"); <---------------and heeeeers the problem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo.getView(int id, int index) is what you should use. Index will change from 0 to X depending on how many Views are sharing the same ID.